# PHP - file_get_contents skip style and script

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to pull a html of a site,

I am using `file_get_contents($url)`.

When I run `file_get_contents` then its takes too much time pull html of host site,
Can I skip style, scripts and images ?

I think then it will take less time to pull html of that site.

Comment: I think excluding some HTML is not possible. But what if you create a script to get contents of a website and store it in DB. When user visits your website, you can query the database and show the result to user. If the website which we are talkin' about gets updated, you have to run your script once again and store new contents in DB.

Comment: I am pulling html for other purpose, not for storing in databse

Comment: Can I ask you that for what purpose you are pulling contents of the `other` website?

Comment: For show current scoreboard

Comment: `file_get_contents` **does not download** images or CSS or JavaScript only the pure source code or in other words the HTML of the targeted page alone.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$file = file_get_contents($url);
$only_body = preg_replace("/.*<body[^>]*>|<\/body>.*/si", "", $file);
```